# datastax opscenter upgrade 4.1.4 to 5.1.4 - no metrics data

Tags: datastax, opscenter

The cassandra is on version 1.2.16. The OpsCenter was on version 4.1.4 and we decided to upgrade to version 5.1.4 to fix some known bugs of the old version. The datastax agents are also upgraded to version 5.1.4.

After the upgrade, there is no data shown on the dashboard. Looking into the log files of the agents, I see many errors like below:

```
ERROR [cassandra-processor-3] 2016-02-20 05:58:18,287 Error when proccessing cassandra callcom.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Unknown identifier key
INFO [install-location-finder] 2016-02-20 05:58:46,656 New JMX connection (127.0.0.1:7199)
INFO [jmx-metrics-1] 2016-02-20 05:58:53,426 New JMX connection (127.0.0.1:7199)
INFO [jmx-metrics-1] 2016-02-20 05:58:53,432 New JMX connection (127.0.0.1:7199)
ERROR [cassandra-processor-2] 2016-02-20 05:59:19,897 Error when proccessing cassandra callcom.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Unknown identifier key
```

After some investigation, I found that OpsCenter table have **"KEY" blob** (note the double quote) as the key column in the schema.

```
CREATE TABLE events (
  "KEY" blob,
  column1 blob,
  value blob,
  PRIMARY KEY ("KEY", column1)
   ...
```

However, when I check another cluster that has no issue, I find that the OpsCenter table key column has **key text** as the definition.

```
CREATE TABLE events (
  key text,
  action bigint,
  level bigint,
  success boolean,
  time bigint,
  PRIMARY KEY ((key))
   ...
```

So the error seems explainable because whenever a metric is being written to an OpsCenter table, it can't find **key** column because the table has **"KEY"** column.  I'm wondering what could do to fix this issue?

Comment: Go to the latest opsc 5.1.4 is old

Comment: Also watch the opscenterd log when you start the service and look for schema propagation errors.

Comment: Thanks phact. Version 5.1.4 is the highest version that is compatible with Cassandra 1.2.16. So unless we upgrade Cassandra version, 5.1.4 is where we can go for now.

Comment: is this helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31856033/datastax-opscenter-upgrade-fails-to-display-stats